# rsync synchronizing files only without creating folders on destination

Tags: rsync

Is it possible with rsync to not create directories on destination?

Imagine I have that source :

```
a/
a/x.txt
b/
b/y.txt
```

And that I have this destination :

```
a/
a/z.txt
```

The wanted result of `rsync source destination` :

```
a/
a/x.txt
a/z.txt
```

Of course my real situation involves thousand files/folders structure and I don't want solutions involving explicit list of synced folders, which I can do. **I'm looking for a clean way just to prevent any folder creation on destination.** By exclude or filtering... That could even be something outside rsync, like a hack with permissions if rsync can't do this...

---

For information, this is really easy to get this kind of situations, in my case I have:

- A server with 2 disks, let's say `A` & `B`. And a local drive `C`.
- I usually use `rsync` to sync (and merge) remote `A` & `B` into local `C`.
- Then sometimes I just want to sync back some `C` files into `A` and `B`. (Just new Files... not non-existing folders on destination)